# parsley.js 'fails' when trying to validate checkbox

Tags: validation, checkbox, parsley.js

We are re-designing a site and part of that re-design involves making the site accessible to screen readers and the like. I'm using latest version (2.8.0). Here's what's happening --- validation for all text, select and textarea fields in our forms work perfectly. In order to be accessible, checkbox and radio inputs are wrapped in  tags. The html for a set of checkboxes looks like this:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <p id="applicant_type_desc" style="margin-bottom: 6px;"><strong>I am: <span class="text-danger" aria-hidden="true">*</span><span class="sr-only">Required</span></strong> <em class="small">(check all that apply)</em></p>
    <div class="checkbox">
        <label id="applicant_type_patient_desc">
            <input type="hidden" name="applicant_type_patient" id="" value="N">
            <input type="checkbox" name="applicant_type_patient" id="applicant_type_patient" value="Y" {checked_applicant_type_patient} aria-labelledby="applicant_type_desc applicant_type_patient_desc" data-parsley-multiple="type" data-parsley-error-message="Please specify whether you are a patient, relative, employee or other."> 
            A patient
        </label>
    </div>
```

followed by more checkbox divs without error messages and ended with an end div for the for form-group wrapper.

If I load the form and click 'submit', all the text fields are validated properly. If I add 'required' to the checkbox above, when 'submit' is clicked nothing happens and the form is submitted with no validation at all.

The same thing happens when I try to validate a radio button set as required.

There is some custom jQuery and parsley code which creates a div to hold all the error messages and transforms the error messages into links to the field id so that a screen reader can follow them and focus on the field in error. But imho, this should have no effect on why the form validation doesn't kick in.

I'm absolutely baffled.

FYI - I tried this using an earlier version (2.0.3) of parsley and the validation actually worked, although all my custom error processing was ignored.

Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Could you post a live example?

Comment: Will do so after the Thanksgiving Holiday.

Comment: I was finally able to create the following fiddle:  [link]https://jsfiddle.net/5bbfdhtp.  in this version, if you run it and click on submit, you'll see the validation for the text fields working properly. then go to the html and add 'required' to the first checkbox field and actually fiddle fails.

Comment: What's even more interesting is that when trying to validate a radio button set, when you lcik submit, you VERY BRIEFLY see the text field errors and then the submit occurs.

Comment: @Marc-AndréLafortune  - any thoughts?

Comment: Thanks for the example. Hard to test on my 11" since it's hardly minimal though. Will check later on my other machine.

Comment: @Marc-AndréLafortune  -  apparently parsley is not adding the data-parsley-id attribute to the checkbox or radio button sets. could it be because of the structure of the html?  i tried changing the name of one of the sets to xxx[] and it did add the data-parsley-multiple attribute="xxx" to all the checkboxes in the set.

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out, parsley handles the errorswrapper element differently for text, textarea and selects then it does for checkboxes and radio buttons.

The starting wrapper element for text, textarea and select contains the parsley-data-id attribute whereas checkbox and radio button elements contain the parsley-data-multiple attribute whether that was generated by parsley or entered manually in the html.

My code was looking for parsley-data-id and, of course the jquery selector failed and generated an error. A colleague was able to spot this for me while we were looking at the page in chrome inspector. Once i saw the error, making a simple adjustment to the form:error event function allowed everything to work.